# Delete item of a list who start with the same words

Tags: python, list

I have a list and many items of this lists begin with "https://www.google.com", so I want to delete all of the elements who start with "https://www.google.com" in my list..

I think I have to use regex but I do not know how to do it..

Thanks,

Comment: show us the code. if you don't have any make an attempt. From the sounds of it regex is not needed for this problem

Comment: `[i for i in YOUR_LIST if not i.startswith( "https://www.google.com" )]` ?

Comment: @Rakesh `list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("https://www.google.com"), YOUR_LIST))` is more pythonic in my opinion

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov [Guido disagrees.](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: @glibdud oh, well, i was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to use regex. We can use substrings to work it out.

```
listOfWebsites=["https://www.google.com",
                "https://www.bing.com", 
                "https://www.facebook.com", 
                "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stack+overflow"]

listOfWebsites=[i for i in listOfWebsites if i[:22]!="https://www.google.com"]
```

Alternatively, you can do what Rakesh said in the OP's comments and use `str.startswith()`

```
listOfWebsites=[i for i in listOfWebsites if i.startswith("https://www.google.com")==False]
```

Comment: Thanks but if now, I want to delete elements in my list who contains "https://www.google.com", how can I do this please ?

Comment: This is very simple in python because you can simply check `if value in string`. So you would do `listOfWebsites=[i for i in listOfWebsites if not ("google.com" in i)]`

Comment: I have an error with this :
`a1 = e)/ragues
numbera1 = sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\b{}\b".format(a1), resp))`

this return : `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 3`